# How can I resolve the error of $write.val is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good Morning,

I just close to my result and I got error on console

1.write is not a function 
2. $write.val is not a function

How I resolve this error how I make the function write in my code . how $write.val is not function where would be define it and how I resolve this type of error.

Here is code

```
$(function() {
    /*$(":input").map((i, el) => el.id).get(),*/
    //var abc = abc();
    //var abc;
    var $write = $(":input").bind('focus', function() {
        $write = $(this).attr('id');
        //console.log(Object.values($write));
        //console.log($write);

        //});   
        //var test=abc();  // this will grab you the return value from firstFunction();
        //alert(test);
        var $write = $write;
        shift = false,
            capslock = false;
        alert($write);
        //console.log(Object.values($write));

        $('#keyboard li').click(function() {
            var $this = $(this),
                character = $this.html(); // If it's a lowercase letter, nothing happens to this variable

            // Shift keys
            if ($this.hasClass('left-shift') || $this.hasClass('right-shift')) {
                $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
                $('.symbol span').toggle();

                shift = (shift === true) ? false : true;
                capslock = false;
                return false;
            }

            // Caps lock
            if ($this.hasClass('capslock')) {
                $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
                capslock = true;
                return false;
            }

            // Delete
            if ($this.hasClass('delete')) {
                var html = $write.html(),
                    txt = html.substr(0, html.length - 1);
                $write.html(txt);
                $write.autocomplete("search", txt);
                return false;
            }

            // Special characters
            if ($this.hasClass('symbol')) character = $('span:visible', $this).html();
            if ($this.hasClass('space')) character = ' ';
            if ($this.hasClass('tab')) character = "\t";
            if ($this.hasClass('return')) character = "\n";

            // Uppercase letter
            if ($this.hasClass('uppercase')) character = character.toUpperCase();

            // Remove shift once a key is clicked.
            if (shift === true) {
                $('.symbol span').toggle();
                if (capslock === false) $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');

                shift = false;
            }

            // Add the character
            $write.val($write.val() + character);
            $write.html(txt);
            $write.autocomplete("search", txt);
        });
    });
});
```

Here is rest of code

```
 $(function () {
     var write = write();   
     write.init("keyboard");
     //first input focus
     var $firstInput = $(":input").first().focus();
     write.currentElement = $firstInput;
     write.currentElementCursorPosition = 0;
 });
```

Comment: what you want do with write function? Because in js or jquery you can use console.log() or document.write(). there is no write() function present.

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: 1.TypeError: write is not a function 2. TypeError: $write.val is not a function